# What will at actually execute?

Tags: linux, at

If I do `atq` I can see a list of what is scheduled via `at` command. But how do I see what is the command that will actually run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
at -c 42
```

where the number is the job number listed by `atq`. `c` is for “cat”.

Non-antique [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) and [*BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=at&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD+3.0) implementations support the `-c` option, as does HP-UX. I think System V, including modern Solaris, doesn't have a way to list the content of pending jobs. On [AIX](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/at.htm), it's `at -lv`.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening us. I kept thinking it was strange that a user's own jobs would be blocked from her. This refers to my earlier answer, since deleted.